# Dynamic data source routing in spring

Tags: spring, postgresql, jakarta-ee, transactions

I've single DB with three identical schema in PostgreSQL.
Now I need to select particular schema for DB operation based on locale-key (store in user session). I found somewhere that this thing is similar to dynamic data source routing.

Anyone have any idea about How to implement this in Spring?
Will this effect transaction management in anyway?
Please do share any sample code if possible.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using this approach:

- First define a [locale interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver) either session-based or change interceptor in your Spring MVC configuration.
- You can now use [`LocaleContexHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html) to fetch the current locale on the attached thread.
- Use [the reference blog post](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) to define your dynamic routing data source. The parameter on your data source router will come from locale. Use `LocaleContextHolder` to determine the locale then use it to determine which data source should be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you have single DB, then the dynamic aspect should not be related to connection pooling - all connections are still for single database. All you need to do is to dynamically set proper schema after starting the transaction.

This may be achieved using some aspect with order higher than `<tx:annotation-driven />`. In this aspect you should acquire current connection:

```
DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource)
```

and issue the following PostgreSQL statement (see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set.html for information about `schema` parameter);

```
set schema 'schemaname-on-the-basis-of-session-parameter';
```

See also [using schemas in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11046152/250517).

As for the transaction management - transactions are related to physical connections and sessions. Schemas on the other side are kind of namespaces, so you don't have to change transaction management, just set current schema at the beginning of each transaction during user request processing.